# Playing audio in background stops working without reason

Tags: ios, audio, background, avaudioplayer

I have an [app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/meloman-vkontakte/id496224452?mt=8) that can play music in background but for some reason some users have issues when app stops playing music in background. I noticed this bug few times on my own iPhone, but I don't understand why this happens?
I'm using AVAudioFoundation.framework

First I register myself for remoteEvents by subclassing `UIWindow`:

```
@interface MelomanWindow : UIWindow

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIResponder *responder;

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
--------------------------------------
@implementation MelomanWindow

@synthesize responder = _responder;
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {
[self.responder remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:receivedEvent];
}
@end
```

And in `AplicationDelegate.m`:

```
[application beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
self.window.responder = [[ApplicationAudioService sharedInstance] playerViewController];
```

After that in my `ViewController` a do this:

```
- (id)init {
...
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
audioSession.delegate = self;
...
}
```

Bug disappears after killing app.
 Also **Remote controller events** not working when this bug appears.
 And also "play" icon not showing in status bar when this bug appears.

Comment: Are you sure this is a "bug" there is quite a long list of triggers that can cause background audio to stop... launching the camera, launching ANY other app that starts a new audio session, etc..

Comment: If I open my app, it resuming to play music and if I push Home button it silencing again. This bug happened only few times for 2 months of using my app. Users getting mad anyway. Something definitely wrong...